# Contractible chain complex

Tags: homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Suppose that we have a chain complex $... \to P_n \to  ... \to P_1 \to P_0 \to 0$ (denote by $d_k:P_K \to P_{k-1}$ the differential of this complex) and suppose that we have $D_k:P_k \to P_{k+1}$ such that $D_{k-1}d_k+d_{k+1}D_k=id_k$ where $k=n-1,n,n+1...$ where $n$ is some fixed natural number. Am I right that this allows us to claim that $H_k(P_*)=0$ for $k=n,n+1,...$? I'm asking this question because I'm little bit confused about indexes: in other words you need "one extra" $D_k$ (namely $D_{n-1}$) in order to have $H_n(P_*)=H_{n+1}(P_*)=...=0$. In particular from the existence of such contracting homotopy you won't get $H_0(P_*)=0$?

Comment: Where exactly in the verification of the claim you are asking about do you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that an extra degree is needed in the hypotheses.  Conceptually, you don't expect the zero-th groups of something contractible to vanish, because you should have the homology of a point.

Note that $H_0(P_*)$ is only zero if $P_1 \to P_0$ is onto.  If there existed a $D_{-1}: 0 \to P_0$ satisfying $D_{-1}d_0 + d_1D_0  = \operatorname{Id}$, then since $D_{-1}$ is the zero map you have $d_1D_0 = \operatorname{Id}$ shows that $d_1$ is onto, as desired.